# want to replace select button with add to cart button in product list

Tags: magento-1.9, php, addtocart, list.phtml

Currently when I click onto a **category** and see a list of **products**, it puts a select button **next** to each product in list mode. Select brings you to the product page.

I would like to replace that select button with an add to cart button that adds the product to the cart from the product list.

Here is my current list.phtml that has select button:   https://bpaste.net/show/e4e3e977c8ee

Here is my attempt at making a list.phtml that has an add to cart button rather than a select button. https://bpaste.net/show/5145c07340f4

Here is my view.phtml file for the actual product page where I stole some of the add to cart code from: https://bpaste.net/show/d147bd4b2464

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I replaced

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Select') ?></span></span></button>
```

with

```
<button class="button related" type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>'"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

And put this at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone help me to solve Add-To-Cart Button error, https://justpaste.it/6olmv